# How to print the powershell cmdlet arguments inside the cmdlet class

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Could someone help me log the actual PowerShell command issued along with arguments.

I have a cmdlet implemented in C# as follows

```
class GetMyCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    // parameter definitions
    ...

    void processRecord()
    {
        // Here I want print actual arguments passed to the cmdlet.
    }
}
```

if someone calls

```
Get-MyCommand -Name Hello -File "test.txt"
```

I just want to log the command in the processRecord function.

```
 "Get-MyCommand -Name Hello -File "test.txt""
```

Clearly I know the cmdlet name, but not sure how to print the exact string of arguments.

Environment.CommandLine works inside regular exes, but how to do the same in cmdlets

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MyInvocation.Line` property on PSCmdlet e.g.:

```
void ProcessRecord() {
    var line = this.MyInvocation.Line
}
```

Comment: Both the above answers are correct and useful to me, marking this as answer as it is clear answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `InvocationInfo` object available as `MyInvocation` member on `PSCmdlet`. It provides info like `Line`, `BoundParameters` etc that will be of use to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo_members(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a caveat to $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.Line:

It only knows the *SINGLE* line that was passed in.  I use it to get a count from the pipeline in my [Get-MailboxTrustee.ps1](https://github.com/JeremyTBradshaw/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-MailboxTrustee.ps1) script, and I've discovered that while this works great:

```
$Mailboxes | .\Get-MailboxTrustee.ps1
```

This does not:

```
$Mailboxes |
.\Get-MailboxTrustee.ps1
```

If you inspect $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.Line in this second example, you will see that it is just:

`.\Get-MailboxTrustee.ps1` (completely missing the `$Mailboxes | <new line>` portion of my command)

Too bad there isn't a $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.Line[***s***].  We know that PowerShell is obviously aware, so $PSCmdlet's implementation seems to be where the lack is.